# Why is Phonegap Facebook Plugin NOT working on 64-bit architectures?

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am refering to the official FBConnect  plugin from phonegap:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect

Everything work fine when working with iphones not x64 (32 bits I assume)

But when launching the app on a 64 bit architecture, this plugin seems to cause trouble. Here is what I have:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/YohannM/Documents/phonegap-facebook-plugin-master/src/ios/frameworks'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/YohannM/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MeetMyFriends-bpzkrmogtgawjxbckzcgadbbsksi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/YohannM/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MeetMyFriends-bpzkrmogtgawjxbckzcgadbbsksi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FacebookConnectPlugin in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLocation in CDVLocation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVLocation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FacebookConnectPlugin in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLocation in CDVLocation.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Of course, I have followed the instructions step by step and (I think) it was working fine previously (beofre I had to update XCode.
Can Anyone help me with this ? what should I do to have it working on my iphone 64 bits ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the solution on another thread, there is one very complete one over there, but the one that worked the best for me wasn't in this thread. It was pretty straighforward:

They just released a new version [3.4.1](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=commitdiff;h=a96d2360fa9cf5bb3006abc37bc88b81d87286d3) that address this issues.

Therefore I update a single file to point to the TAG 3.4.1:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/platforms.js
```

line 24 
from:

```
version: '3.4.0'
```

to:

```
version: '3.4.1'
```

Then you remove the iOS folder in your project and run:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

This will download the new template based on 3.4.1 with all the patches.

thank You @Fabrizio Giordano for pointing that out